# Running a plain python interpreter in presense of ipython with manage.py shell

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

I have ipython installed, I want to run a plain python interpreter instead with manage.py shell.

So I try,

```
python2.5 manage.py shell --plain
```

Which gave me an error, and text which suggest that --plain was passed to ipython

So I read, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

which suggets

```
django-admin.py shell --plain
```

Which gives me

```
Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Which seem the correct thing for it to do.

What am I mising here? [Ubuntu Jaunty,  django.VERSION = (1, 2, 0, 'alpha', 0), python 2.5 and 2.6]

Comment: Both `./manage.py shell --plain` and `/usr/bin/python manage.py shell --plain` work as expected for me.  I just aliased python to ipython; did you do something less common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reason you want to use python's interpretor over iPython's is because you need to paste the doc tests, you can try typing

```
%doctest_mode
```

in the ipython console instead

```
In [1]: %doctest_mode
*** Pasting of code with ">>>" or "..." has been enabled.
Exception reporting mode: Plain
Doctest mode is: ON
>>>
```

Comment: What if you just really prefer the plain python interpreter? This answer may have solved the OP's problem but is not actually responsive to the question as stated.

Answer (score 0):

[link to a blog post explaining the same thing for bpython](http://proteus-tech.com/blog/code-garden/bpython-django/)